# 500 Internal Server when Inserting data to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am attempting to test my database by inserting some basic data into a MySQL database, but I keep getting an error. After checking with Advanced Rest Client, it tells me it's a `500 Internal Server Error`. I can't seem to figure out what i'm doing wrong at this point. This is my PHP Code

```
<?php

//redacted password
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "mypass", "user_data");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$firstname          = "John";
$lastname           = "Smith";
$email              = "email@domain.com";
$password           = "testpass";
$uuid               = uniqid('', true);
$hash               = $this->hashSSHA($password);
$encrypted_password = $hash["encrypted"]; // encrypted password
$salt               = $hash["salt"]; // salt

$sql = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO userinfo_basic(userid, firstname, lastname, email, encrypted_password, salt, created_at) VALUES('$uuid', '$firstname', '$lastname' '$email', '$encrypted_password', '$salt', NOW())");

if ($sql == true) {

    echo "User Successfully Added!";

} else {

    echo "User could not be added";

}



mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

If there's anything I need to change or add, please ask. All Help is appreciated!

Comment: In your else condition do `mysqli_error($con)` to see what the error is !

Comment: @SulthanAllaudeen I guess I should have specified this, the PHP code does not return anything. Checking with Advanced Rest Client, it tells me "Response does not contain any data". So when I run it in my browser, the screen returns blank.

Comment: Just assign the query to a variable like this `$sql = "INSERT INTO userinfo_basic(userid, firstname, lastname, email, encrypted_password, salt, created_at) VALUES('$uuid', '$firstname', '$lastname' '$email', '$encrypted_password', '$salt', NOW())");` and then print it like `echo $sql` and paste it in your phpmyadmin and see for the error, It is the way you can debug yourself :)

Comment: Hopefully those variables are never going to be user input. If they are you are open to SQL injections. You should try to not pass variables into your query. Use prepared statements instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've missed a comma after `'$lastname'`.

Change:

```
INSERT INTO userinfo_basic(userid, firstname, lastname, email, encrypted_password, salt, created_at) VALUES('$uuid', '$firstname', '$lastname' '$email', '$encrypted_password', '$salt', NOW())
```

To:

```
INSERT INTO userinfo_basic(userid, firstname, lastname, email, encrypted_password, salt, created_at) VALUES('$uuid', '$firstname', '$lastname', '$email', '$encrypted_password', '$salt', NOW())
```

Comment: Can't believe I missed that! Thank you.